# LocalStorage of RNG Image

Tags: javascript, html, random, storage, local

I have created a random number generator connected to an array of images, one of these images are shown randomly to the user when they load the page.

I'm struggling to figure out how to put one of these images in local storage so the same image does not appear when they reload the page, I just do not know how to do it.

Here is my JSFiddle if you need it, I don't know how to show the images on these though I hope that doesn't cause issues: https://jsfiddle.net/Syystole/10mxjs9v/4/

HTML

```
<img src="" width="305" height="312" id="myPicture" alt="some image">
```

JS

```
window.onload = choosePic; // Run Function When Website Runs
var myPix = new Array("./images/service2.png","./images/service3.png","./images/service4.png"); //Array of 3

function choosePic() {
    randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * myPix.length)); //Random Number Generator based on the number of pictures in array
    document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum]; //Random Number with image is set in HTML
}
```

Comment: Don't put the _image_ in local storage, just put the random number(s) chosen.  Are you trying to avoid using the same image just one time on reload?  For example, is image7, image3, image7 acceptable? Or do you never want to show the same image, until you've run out of available images?

Comment: Yes, just not the same image twice

Answer (score 0):

You could store the index of the last image in the local storage when it is chosen:

```
localStorage.setItem('lastViewedImage', randomNum);
```

And then also check for the last viewed images index when running your choosePic and handle not selecting the same image however you see fit:

```
var lastViewedImage = localStorage.getItem('lastViewedImage');
if (lastViewedImage == randomNum) {
    // Handle collision
}
```

Edit:

```
function choosePic {
    // Get the index of the last viewed image
    var lastViewedImage = localStorage.getItem('lastViewedImage');
    // Use a temp array as not to modify the array storing the images
    var tempArr = myPix;
    if (lastViewedImage != null) {
        // Remove the used image from the temp copy of the picture array
        tempArr.splice(lastViewedImage, 1);
    }
    //Random Number Generator based on the number of pictures in temp array 
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempArr.length);
    // Update the stored index with the new used images index
    localStorage.setItem('lastViewedImage', randomNum);
    //Random Number with image is set in HTML
    document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum]; 
}
```

Edit 2:

This is actually a bad solution. Since the used index is the index of the item in the temp array, the index would not apply to the temp array that would be generated on a subsequent execution of the function. Hopefully this will give you some ideas on how to solve your problem though.

Comment: So I'm storing the number the RNG created correct?
How would I stop the same image from appearing once it is detected though? 

Is it possible to just ignore a number and start the RNG again without that number?

Comment: You could call your choosePic function again, but this would be annoying an could run over and over. Instead of checking the used index against the random number, you could splice your array to remove the already chosen image so that it isn't even an option, but you would need to update your random number generator to handle the new array length.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ken,  I just have no idea how to "splice the array". I would appreciate it.greatly if you could help me

Comment: So once you get your used index from the localStorage, you would remove the used image from the array with something like myPix.splice(lastViewedImage, 1). This will start at the index of the offending image (lastViewedImage) and remove one item from the array (the image). Then you would select your image from the array since all of the images would be valid options.

Comment: @Syystole Please check my latest edit, I have added an example of what I described here in my comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep looping over your random number pick until it is different than the last chosen number.
Note - due to the nature of randomness you could keep coming up with the same number over and over, and end up looping ten-hundred-million times which would kill your page, but due to the nature of probability the likelihood of that happening is negligible.

```
// somewhere
var myPix = new Array("./images/service2.png","./images/service3.png","./images/service4.png");

function choosePic() {
    // Get the last number stored.
    var lastViewedImage = localStorage.getItem('lastViewedImage');
    // Set a very high number if none was stored before.
    if (lastViewedImage === null) lastViewedImage = 65535;

    // Keep looping as long as we come up with the same number.
    var random = 0;
    do {
        random = Math.floor((Math.random() * myPix.length));
    } while (random === lastViewedImage);

    // Got a different number, save it and return the image
    localStorage.setItem('lastViewedImage', random);
    return myPix[random];
}

// Use as:
document.getElementById("myPicture").src = choosePic();
```

This hard-codes the name of the image array in the `choosePic` function, which is generally considered bad practice; you could pass the array to choosePic, but then should consider how to handle the random number if you pass different arrays (left as an exercise for the reader).